# How to automatically change model fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model and I want to know if it is possible to set a condition that triggers a change in the model field. For example, I have a model

```
class BillboardTracker(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    expiry_date = models.DateField()
    is_expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to know if it is possible to have a function in the model that makes is_expired equals to True when the expiry date is up. I tried this

```
def expire(self):
     if datetime.now == self.expiry_date:
        self.is_expired = True
```

but it's not working. Is it possible to implement this?

Comment: Yes, but you need to *call* the now function: `datetime.now()`. Also note that you probably want to check that now is *greater than* the expiry date, otherwise this'll only work if you call it at the exact same time as the expiry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Use a @property

The simplest thing here is not to have an is expired field at all! It's not needed. What you need is a property.

```
class BillboardTracker(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    expiry_date = models.DateField()

    @property
    def is_expired(self):
        if datetime.now > self.expiry_date:
            return True
        return False
```

Remember, you don't have a field in a database, if that field is the same as another field with a simple calculation. This automatically eliminates your head ache of having to flag items as expired.

If you want to find out if an object has expired.

```
 if instance.is_expired == True:
    print 'yes, that ones gone'
```

### Filtering

If you wanted to retrieve a whole set of objects that have expired

```
BillboardTracker.objects.filter(expiry_date__le=datetime.now())
```

This is why I mentioned that you don't need to store a field that can be easily calculated.

### Index advantage

In most RDBMS a boolean field (such as your is_expired column) cannot be indexed effectively. So that actually means the above query will be faster than a query on that boolean field provided you create an index on the expiry_date field.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Now when I define that function do I need to call it like BillboardTracker.expire? or the function will run automatically whenever I create a new object

Comment: ow there isn't a need to store the expire status in the database so there isn't a need to run this automatically.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, I'm new to django, I'm using djangoframework viewsets, how do I add this to my viewsets. is it in the perform_create function?

Comment: As I said there *isn't a field in the databse now* because *it isn't needed* so there isn't a need to have it in perform_create or anything. All your create/update operations can ignore that field. That field is purely an virtual one :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes in this function,
Firstly use **datetime.now()** and secondly,

You might want to update your logic like this :

```
def expire(self):
     if datetime.now() >= self.expiry_date:
        self.is_expired = True
        return True
     else:
        return False
```

Because sometimes both the values might not be exactly same but still **BillboardTracker** need is_expired = True for all previous dates.

And in your views :

```
 def your_view(request):
    instance = BillboardTracker.objects.get(id=some_id)
    if instance.is_expired() == True:
        print 'expired'
    else:
        print 'fresh'
```

Comment: After defining this function, how do i run it?

Comment: @HackAfro In your view whenever you are saving any object in the table, check if object.expire() returns true or false.

Comment: @HackAfro Updated my answer.Please check now.

Comment: Thanks I'm using DRF viewsets, will this work the same way?

Comment: @HackAfro In rest api also,the model behaviour is always the same. It will work for that also.