# Function that filter the future posts with datetime.now() - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to make a function inside a model that don't return the post published in a future.

This is the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime


class ModelPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=70,
        unique=True,
        )
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(
                        default=timezone.now,
                        )
    contents = models.TextField(
        max_length=200,
        blank=True,
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def is_future(self):
        if self.publishing_date > datetime.now()
            return True
        return False
```

The views is this:

```
def listPostsOnline(request):
    posts_list = BlogPost.objects.all()  #filter(published=True)
    context = {"posts_list": posts_list}
    template = 'blog/reading/list_post_online.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

And this is the template:

```
{% for p in posts_list %}
  {% if not p.is_future %}
  <div class="container my-4">
    <h3><a href="{{ p.get_absolute_url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></h3>
    <h5>{{ p.publishing_date|date:"d - M - Y | G:i:s" }}</h5>
  </div>
  {% else %}
  <div class="container-full">
    <h1>No data!</h1>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that I have this error

> module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

attributed to `is_future` and I not be able to resolve.

**UPDATE**

I was inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505243/how-to-automatically-change-model-fields-in-django)

**FIRST TRY**

I've put `from datetime import datetime` instead of `import datetime` and I see this error:

> can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

**SECOND TRY**

With `import datetime` I've put `if self.publishing_date > datetime.datetime.now():` instead of `if self.publishing_date > datetime.now():` and I see again this:

> can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution here is to use `django.utils.timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.now()`